# Django ModelForm with prefix

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a template with 2 forms. I would like to use "prefix" parameter to have different id in my rendered template like that :

My first form :

```
<input id="id_folder-name" maxlength="75" name="folder-name" type="text" />
```

My second form :

```
<input id="id_file-name" maxlength="75" name="file-name" type="text" />
```

I my view, I instantiate forms :

```
self.form_class(prefix="folder")
self.form_class_upload(prefix="file")
```

but it doesn't work, see console log :

```
[23/Aug/2013 11:15:57] "GET /sample/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1037
invalid
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_name" maxlength="75" name="name" type="text" /></td></tr>
[23/Aug/2013 11:16:50] "POST /sample/new-folder/ HTTP/1.1" 200 634
```

So it doesn't call my form_valid method...

I don't understand why Django doesn't consider 'prefix' parameter for validation form.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Inode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files", null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Inode

class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Inode
        fields = ['name', 'file']

class NewFolderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Inode
        fields = ['name']
```

views.py :

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .forms import FileUploadForm, NewFolderForm
from .models import Inode

class MainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "sample/browser.html"
    form_class = NewFolderForm
    form_class_upload = FileUploadForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['form_new_folder'] = self.form_class(prefix="folder")
        context['form_upload'] = self.form_class_upload(prefix="file")
        context["inodes"] = [i for i in Inode.objects.all()]

        return context


class NewFolderView(FormView):
    template_name = "sample/browser.html"
    form_class = NewFolderForm
    success_url = "/sample"

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        invalid = super(NewFolderView, self).form_invalid(form)
        print "invalid"
        print form
        return invalid

    def form_valid(self, form):
        isvalid = super(NewFolderView, self).form_valid(form)
        print "valid"
        return isvalid
```

template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='fr' xml:lang='fr'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'sample-new-folder' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form_new_folder}}
      <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'sample-upload' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form_upload}}
      <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

rendered template :

```
<html lang='fr' xml:lang='fr'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>sample</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <form method="post" action="/sample/new-folder/">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='btopdI8WyHgqG2ZSTG81yhmaDa9Rk7Is' />
      <tr><th><label for="id_folder-name">Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_folder-name" maxlength="75" name="folder-name" type="text" /></td></tr>
      <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="/sample/upload/">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='btopdI8WyHgqG2ZSTG81yhmaDa9Rk7Is' />
      <tr><th><label for="id_file-name">Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_file-name" maxlength="75" name="file-name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_file-file">File:</label></th><td><input id="id_file-file" name="file-file" type="file" /></td></tr>
      <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you passing those prefixes? You don't show it in the view that you've posted.